# Did Aristotle accuse Plato of distorting Socrates?

Tags: aristotle, plato, socrates

It is always said that Plato sometimes put his words in the Socrates's mouth. Aristotle is the contemporary and critic of Plato. If Plato misattributed some Platonian notions to Socrates, Aristotle was the best one to expose him. Did Aristotle somewhere accuse Plato of distorting Socrates?

Comment: No. Aristotle was not even born at the time of Socrates's death, and spent formative years at Plato's Academy, so he was not in a position to detect Plato's distortions, if any. Some historians complain that "*Aristotle's testimony is completely dependent on Plato, for his interpretations of Socrates are based on Platonic dialogues*", and it is largely discarded by those trying to reconstruct Socrates's views, see [Graham, Socrates and Plato](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4182408).

Comment: Aristotle was not born at the time of Parmenides or Heraclitus, too. But he reports their ideas which are not always included in Plato's dialogues.

Comment: The difference is that those authors left books which were still accessible in Aristotle's time. Socrates did not, what Aristotle and others knew of him was word of mouth. And what Aristotle does report is transparently derived from Plato's dialogues, in scholars' opinion.

Comment: You are right about the difference. But Aristotle arguably encountered many persons in Academy or other places who had seen Socrates. His sources on Socrates could not be limited to Plato.

Comment: Whatever his sources and reasons for accepting Plato's account could be, his texts that came down to us do not have what you are looking for.

Comment: The main point in accusing Plato of distorting Socrates is made through other students of Socrates who also wrote books, yet have different meaning from Plato's. It is doubtful whether Socrates had a fully developed metaphysics in the Platonic sense, so yes it is possible Plato many times uses Socrates, as a vehicle for his own philosophy